# Can you check for existing Stack Exchange accounts before creating duplicates Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, merge-accounts

I recently answered a question on the Cognitive Science stack exchange site and since I hadn't used that site before I had to create a new login. After creating the login I realized that the new site wasn't linked to my existing sites through StackExchange even though I used the same email and username of the original account when signing up for the new site. I think this might be because I used the Login button that appears after you start answering a question.

Answer (score 4):

Using the same email and credential type is *supposed* to link your site profiles up with the same network account. And it does - you didn't actually use the same email, although they are very, very similar.

I'll anonymize since we are in a public area here, but basically what happened was that your account that you're posting with here on MSO is using `robert.frost@example.org` (where example.org is actually Gmail, but you get the idea). Your CogSci profile, however, has subtly different credentials: `bobfrost@example.org`.

I can make this connection because I'm reading your account information and I'm a <s>cat pretending to be a</s> human capable for parsing English and extrapolating connections. However, there isn't really a way for us to automatically link up users with different emails and no other correlation between profiles.

I will merge these accounts for you and you'll be able to use either set of credentials to sign in going forward. You can view the credentials you used by clicking "my logins" from your user profile on any SE site you joined.

Comment: "I'm a human capable for parsing..." - I thought you were a cat.

Comment: @Mysticial Fixed. ;)

Comment: Sorry I guess I used a different email address.