# Forgot to sign in: duplicated account

Tags: bug

It seems I am not the only one facing this problem, when you accidentally create a new, duplicate account. For example like this:

- You enter one of many stackoverflow or stackexchange sites, and post your question - just to realize you didn't log in.
- The site asks you to sign in as a completely user#####. Inadvertently you *already posted* as user#####.
- You click on "sign in with google" and type your credentials for your external account
- The system properly recognizes that the google account you signed in has already the SO/SE account. And you end up being logged in with your main
- but.... the question you posted is owned by now-defunct and not fully registered user####.

As a result, inadvertedly, you became an owner of two accounts. What is worse, one of which is actually not reachable as it didn't undergo full registration process. As a result you cannot simply remove it and re-post the question from the main account.

It will require administrator attention to merge the two accounts. It costs your and my time. I have seen few more questions on meta about incidents similar to mine when someone accidentally posted as a new user.

[How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

[Can you check for existing Stack Exchange accounts before creating duplicates Stack Exchange accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271661/can-you-check-for-existing-stack-exchange-accounts-before-creating-duplicates-st)

[Need Help in deleting my duplicate account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188416/need-help-in-deleting-my-duplicate-account)

Any ideas or plans on how to prevent such situation in the first place?
Maybe keep the question/answer "unposted" until the registration is actually complete?

I am not talking about situation when somebody *wants* to have multiple accounts for whatever reason (e.g. bypass suspension). I am just referring to a situation when this happened by accident.

Answer (score -2):

> Any ideas or plans on how to prevent such situation in the first place?

StackOverflow lets you add multiple logins to your account through its *Add a login* page, available at:

## https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add

To get to this page normally you'd visit your own profile, click on the *my logins* link, and then click *add more logins...* on the modal pop-up which appears.

Comment: But there is nothing to add? I use a single login (through google in my case). When I posted as user#### I was using the very same google login, but *after* and not before posting.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you meant you'd originally created your account through Google and then accidentally created another account by logging in with a different service.